# Stack Exchange Cross-Platform Chat Application

Tags: discussion, chat, stackapps

There is nothing out there as far as an application goes that will allow you to have open, and manage, multiple chat "rooms" or "sessions" for chat.stackoverflow.com.

I'm proposing creating such an app and would like your input. The stack will consist of [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) + [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) targeting a browser-based hosted service and then compiled into Android and iOS apps lastly.

Comment: I think http://stackapps.com/ is the appropriate place for this.

Comment: @George is right, you are free to create such an app, Stack Exchange are not likely to do it any time soon. (Or not soon actually)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In 6 to 8 soons ...

Comment: To be clear, you're saying you want to make an app, not that you want us to make an app with those technologies?

Comment: With the amount of coders on SO, just put a nice bounty on it and in a week there are enough apps. Like way too much enough.